# CSS Only Working on First Angular Selector

Tags: css, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to apply css to my Angular selector. It works on the first one, but not the next two. They're all the same selector.

#### citation.dart

```
library citation_component;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:citation/tooltip/tooltip.dart' show TooltipModel;

@Component(
    selector: 'citation',
    template: '<span class="citation-text" tooltip="tooltipForFootnote()">{{citationText}}</span>',
    cssUrl: 'citation.css')

class CitationComponent
{
  @NgAttr('bibliographicEntry')
  int bibliographicEntry;

  @NgAttr('citationText')
  String citationText;

  // Set up the decorator
  static final tooltip = new Expando<TooltipModel>();

  TooltipModel tooltipForFootnote()
  {
    if (tooltip[this] == null)
    {
      tooltip[this] = new TooltipModel(bibliographicEntry);
    }
    return tooltip[this];
  }
}
```

#### citation.css

```
.citation-text { border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080; }
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Citable Prototype</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Blow Family</h1>
<p>Joe Blow born <citation bibliographicEntry="1" citationText="12 Apr 1858">  </citation></p>

<p>Robin Blow born <citation bibliographicEntry="1" citationText="9 Jan 1852">   </citation></p>

<p>This is a long entry to see what happens when the tooltip hits the right side of the page John Blow born <citation bibliographicEntry="2" citationText="13 Dec 1850"></citation></p>

<div style="visibility: hidden;">
  <div id="be1">
    <h2>Citation 1</h2>
    <p>source specification</p>
    <p>additional information</p>
  </div>

  <div id="be2">
    <h2>Citation 2</h2>
    <p>source specification</p>
    <p>additional information</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### screen shot

[image]

The tooltip decorator works on all three.

I usually serve the app through a virtual host entry and an Apache server. I also tried running pub serve and accessing it through http://localhost:8080. I get the same problem. When I tried http://localhost:8081, I got a 404 error. I also tried the Chromium browser. I've always got a log of error when I try to run the dart code directly as opposed to the build. I ran pub serve and tried http://localhost:8080 in Chromium. I had the same problem.

#### Debug output

This is what I saw when I did inspect element in Chromium.

[image]

The working and non-working entries appear identical. Very strange. FYI, I changed the css class to cite-text since my initial post.

#### More debug output

When I do inspect element on the second occurrence and view computed styles, I get:

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
display: inline;
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

The working entry had what you would expect to have it display correctly.

#### browser test

I tried the site in other browsers. I doesn't work in Chrome and Chromium. It works in Firefox and Safari. And now it works in Chrome! I stopped and restarted Chrome before seeing it working.

Comment: Weird, have you tried to investigate in Chrome DevTools?

Comment: What tool exactly? Do you mean using Chromium and dartium?

Comment: Yes, investigate the DOM and look why the CSS is not applied.

Comment: Looks fine. When you select the second `<span class="cite-text...">` is the `border-bottom: ...` listed in the CSS attributes?

Comment: Did you check in Dartium or Chrome. Can you please also check with the other browser and check if it behaves the same?

Comment: I don't know where the CSS attributes are listed. I took my best shot and added it to the question. There is a difference that explains why it's not rendering correctly.

Comment: It seems to be a browser issue. If this is in Dartium (Chromium) please also test in Chrome.

Comment: The citations don't actually have the class of `.citation-text` applied to them, hence you cannot target them. Are you able to do it the more 'traditional' way, instead of using the shadow DOM?

Comment: Sorry Alex, I changed the class tag to cite-text after my initial post because I thought it might have been a duplicate name.

Comment: If it works in Chrome it's a Dartium bug. Please report at http://dartbug.com and please add a link to this SO question.